# Parsing Json witth Gson in Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to parse a local json file and the output is not what it's supposed to show.
I have little experience with Json (and Gson) so I'm unclear as to what the problem is.

Here is the tweet class:

```
    public class tweet {
         String from_user;
         String from_user_name;
         String profile_image_url;
         String text;

    public tweet(){
        //empty constructor
            }
}
```

This is the class where Gson is used:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class tweetfeedreader {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "C:/Users/LILITH/Desktop/jsonfile.json"));
        tweet J_tweet = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, tweet.class);
        System.out.println(J_tweet);
    }
}
```

Lastly, the .json file which i have saved onto a local directory:
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%40android

there are no errors, but the output is:

```
tweet@3030d5aa
```

I'm uncertain as to what might be going wrong, so thanks for your guidance!

[Edit: I forgot to add that I have searched SO before and read the related posts. They may be similar but I am not having much luck in piecing the pieces together.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strip the results array out of that json, leaving nothing outside the []s.

Then this was just about the least I could modify the code to get it working:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.reflect.*;

public class tweetfeedreader {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "jsonfile.json"));
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) sb.append(line);
    Type tweetCollection = new TypeToken<Collection<tweet>>(){}.getType();
    Collection<tweet> tweets = gson.fromJson(line, tweetCollection);
    for (final tweet t : tweets) System.out.println(t.text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the contents of jsonfile.json?

Comment: I copied everything from http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%40android into jsonfile.json

Comment: You're probably right, but I'm getting a NullPointerException at the foreach loop at the end. hm.. i'm trying to see why it's coughing up NPE, but thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry - I switched a variable out and put the wrong one back in, change the fromJson(line, to fromJson(sb.toString(),

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17986/discussion-between-whitebit-and-rich)

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(J_tweet);
```

log in console reference on object `J_tweet` (`tweet@3030d5aa`)
Add method `toString()` to your `tweet` class
for example

```
@Override 
public String toString()  
{  
   return "from_user: " + from_user + "; from_user_name : " + from_user_name;     
}
```